# creating a GUI in Tkinter - new windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

help! I have been working on this simple GUI for DAYS and I just can't understand how to make it work. I am trying to get the "YES" button to open a new window that then runs the sql database created later in the code. I can't get the database to work in the new window (top).

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3
import typing


root = Tk()
root.title('You are invited!')
root.option_add('*Font', 'Times 24')
root['bg'] = '#49A'


frame = LabelFrame
top = Toplevel()


def myClick_No():
    myLabel = Label(root, text="We're sorry we won't see you there. Thanks for letting us know.",bg='#fff', fg='#f00', pady=10, padx=10, font=10)
    myLabel.grid(row=6, column = 0)
    button_quit = Button(top, text="Exit",     command=root.destroy)
    button_quit.grid(row=2, column=5)

def myClick_Yes():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("We can't wait to see you!")
    top['bg'] = '#49A'
    myLabel = Label(top, text="We're so excited to see you. Please provide RSVP     details  *Due to current COVID restictions only 4 guest per party allowed*", fg='#fff', bg='#49A')
    myLabel.grid(row=1, column = 0)
    button_quit = Button(top, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button_quit.grid(row=10, column=5)


#create label widget (no action!)
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="YOU'RE INVITED!", fg='#fff', bg='#49A')
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="A NIGHT TO REMEMBER", fg='#fff', bg='#49A')
myLabel3 = Label(root, text="FRIDAY, DECEMBER 24, 2021", fg='#fff', bg='#49A')
myLabel4 = Label(root, text="6PM IN THE EVENING", fg='#fff', bg='#49A')

#Creates a frame for the RSVP Options
RSVPFrame = LabelFrame(root,text="WILL YOU ATTEND?", fg='#fff', bg='#000080',     padx=15, pady=15)

#layout
myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=0)
myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=0)
myLabel4.grid(row=3, column=0)
RSVPFrame.grid(row=4, column=0)

#create a button widget with action and size options, command= calls the function
myButtonNo = Button(RSVPFrame, text="No", padx=10, pady=10, command=myClick_No)
myButtonNo.grid(row=5, column=1)
myButtonYes = Button(RSVPFrame, text="Yes", padx=10, pady=10, command=myClick_Yes)
myButtonYes.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_quit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_quit.grid(row=20, column=5)
       

#create a database 
conn = sqlite3.connect("guest_meal_selection.db")

#create cursor, commit changes 
c = conn.cursor()

#create table
'''c.execute("""CREATE TABLE guest_meal (
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    meal_choice text,
    )""")
'''

#create submit function for database
def submit():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("guest_meal_selection.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

#insert into table
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO guest_meal (FirstName, LastName, MealChoice) VALUES {
                FirstName: FirstName.get(),
                LastName: LastName.get(),
                MealChoice: MealChoice.get()
            })""")

          
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


    FirstName.delete(0, END)
    LastName.delete(0, END)
    MealChoice.delete(0, END)

#create Query function for event planner to pull all RSVps from database

def query():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("guest_meal_selection.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM guest_meal")
    RSVPs = c.fetchall()
    print()

#loop through results
    for RSVP in RSVPs:
        print_RSVPs = str(RSVP) + "/n"

    QueryLabel = Label(top, text=print_RSVPs)
    Querylabel=grid(row=7, column=0)


    conn.commit()
    conn.close()    



#create text boxes
FirstName = Entry(top, width=30)
FirstName.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20)

LastName = Entry(top, width=30)
LastName.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)

MealChoice = Entry(top, width=30)
MealChoice.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20)


#create text box labels

FirstNameLabel = Label(top, text="First name", bg='#49A')
FirstNameLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

LastNameLabel = Label(top, text="Last name", bg='#49A')
LastNameLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

MealChoiceLabel = Label(top, text="Meal Choice", bg='#49A')
MealChoiceLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)


#create text box submit button
SubmitButton = Button(top, text="Submit", command=submit)
SubmitButton.grid(row=5, column=1)

#create query botton
QueryButton = Button(top, text=" Show RSVP List", command=query)
QueryButton.grid(row=6, column=1)
                  
conn.commit()

conn.close()

root.mainloop()
```

I just don't understand!

Comment: Your code failed to run due to `NameError: name 'myLabel' is not defined`.  Fix the indentation issue of your code.

Comment: It works fine in my .py when I run that. I just can't get the database to run. It must be something from the copy and paste into the text box causing the indentation to be off.

Comment: Your updated code still failed to run due to `NameError: name 'top' is not defined` on the line `FirstName = Entry(top, width=30)`.  Try testing your posted code first.

Comment: It works for me in idle. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: The INSERT SQL statement is incorrect.  Try `c.execute("INSERT INTO guest_meal (FirstName, LastName, MealChoice) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (FirstName.get(), LastName.get(), MealChoice.get()))`.